# how to increase the input line length(max) in windows?

Tags: windows-xp, batch-file

in my one batch file i set a variable,
after running this batch file it shows the error
"The input line is too long."
how to overcome from this problem.
or it is possible to increase the input line length(max) in windows?

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment, to delimit a line in a batch file, append the `^` character to the line. Eg:

```
somelong command ^
carries on here ^
and finally ends here
```

This will behave as 1 line.

Not however if this will overcome the input length limitation.

Comment: @Benoit: Jeez, thanks for typo fix, it confused the hell out of me just now  ;P MOAR COFFEE!

Comment: u can haz kophee. I think you had delimited too much in your answer. :)