# 'Input line is too long error' when trying to activate python 3.5 on anaconda

Tags: python

I am attempting to install a python 3 kernel for my ipython notebook using anaconda. This is to enable me use Python 2 or 3 when needed. So I found the commands below on this stackoverflow page [Using both Python 2.x and Python 3.x in IPython Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30492623/using-both-python-2-x-and-python-3-x-in-ipython-notebook)

```
conda create -n py35 python=3.5
source activate py35
conda install notebook ipykernel
ipython kernel install
```

The issue is after installing python 3.5 the `source activate py35`command gives `source is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`error and when I use `activate py35`, I get a `the input line is too long` Please is there a way to fix this error?

Comment: It is just activate `activate ...` on windows http://conda.pydata.org/docs/py2or3.html#install-a-different-version-of-python

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34818282/anaconda-prompt-loading-error-the-input-line-is-too-long)

I basically created a new system variable in my anaconda directory and added it's path variables in front of the existing ones. The `"activate py35"` command then worked very fine.